# Realise result of every query in a string

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, clojure

I am new to Clojure and working on a jdbc application where I have a string with three queries defined in that string as shown below.

```
(def tpch_query15
      (str "create view revenue0 (supplier_no, total_revenue) as select l_suppkey, sum(l_extendedprice * (1 - l_discount)) "
        "from lineitem where l_shipdate >= date '1993-04-01' and l_shipdate < date '1993-04-01' + interval '3' month group by l_suppkey; "
            "select s_suppkey, s_name, s_address, s_phone, total_revenue from supplier, revenue0 where s_suppkey = supplier_no "
        "and total_revenue = (select max(total_revenue) from revenue0) order by s_suppkey LIMIT 1; drop view revenue0"))

(defn run-a-query
  "Run a query three times and return the average time."
  [conn-db query queryno]
  (println (str "Running query " queryno))
  (let [starttime (System/currentTimeMillis)]
    (dotimes [n 3]
      (try
        (let
          [rs (sql/query conn-db query)]
        ;; Print column names with | as delimiter
        (dorun 0 (map #(println (clojure.string/join " | " (keys %))) rs))
        ;; Print a seperator between column names and rows
        (println "------------------------------------------------------")
        ;; Print rows with | as delimiter
        (dorun (map #(println (clojure.string/join " | " (vals %))) rs)))
        (catch Exception e)))
      (/ (- (System/currentTimeMillis) starttime) 3.0)))

;;https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/conj!
(defn run-all-queries
  "Run all TPC-H queries. Return a vector of average time taken for each query."
  [conn-db]
  (loop [i 0 v (transient [])]
    (if (< i 22)
      (recur (inc i) (conj! v (run-a-query conn-db (get queries-to-run i) (+ i 1))))
      (persistent! v))))
```

Is it possible to have run-a-query function print the results of all three queries defined in that string. Currently when run-a-query is passed tpch_query15 it does not print out any results. From what I understand, this is because the last of three queries which is a drop view does not return a result set and it will only return the last query result.

Answer (score 0):

Reformulate your query as a single SQL SELECT statement using WITH clause (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html) instead of creating and then dropping a view:

```sql
with
  revenue0 (supplier_no, ...) as (select l_suppkey, ... )
select s_suppkey, ...
from supplier, revenue0,...
```

You really don't need a view here, with or without Clojure, JDBC etc. And in any case, mixing DDL with queries/DML on the same connection (and especially within the same request) is generally a bad idea - the performance may suffer greatly, depending on the database, version, driver etc.